# How do I embed an After Effects animation into my website?

Tags: jquery, html, css, after-effects

I'm new to coding and am trying my best to learn as I go along whilst creating my personal website. My current struggle comes in the form of after effects. So I have created an animation for my websites welcome screen which includes my logo and a welcome message inside of after effects. However, I am stuck getting it from after effects into Brackets. I tried rendering it as a .mov file but this isn't really what i want. Is there a work around to this?

P.s. I have tried using the bodymovin extension but I can't get that to work for me either. Its frustrating having all the ideas and visuals but not being able to transfer them into code form. I apologise in advance if there is a simple work around that i have missed.

Many thanks!

Comment: AfterEffects...erm, *effects* are specific to video as I recall. There *may* be some web equivalents (or similarities) but they aren't directly interchangable or transferable.

Comment: If you want the animation you are going to have to render it somehow in the way a browser can display them, .mov for example (probably too big of a file) or maybe .webm then you can have some javascript hide the video after it is done playing to display your site.

Comment: why haven't you been abled to use bodymovin. Can you share some code of what you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Export a compressed video  - an .mp4. Then use the `<video>` tag to embed it:

```
<video src="/path/to/your/video.mp4" autoplay poster="/path/to/placeholderImage.png">Message to users here if their browser doessn't support the video tag (unlikely)</video>
```

Read more about the video tag here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video